# Proposal to narrow the scope of 'paper-submission'

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the tag wiki excerpt for [paper-submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-submission) defines the scope of this tag as follows:

> The process of preparing a scientific manuscript, finding suitable journal or conference and submitting the manuscript for publication.

This seems overly broad to me. There is so much entropy in questions with this tag that it is practically meaningless. It's become a catch-all tag for everything related to publishing academic papers, which we already have in [publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publications). Furthermore,

- "The process of preparing a scientific manuscript" is already covered pretty thoroughly by other tags: [writing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing), [formatting](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting), [typesetting](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting), and probably some others I haven't thought of.
- On "finding suitable journal or conference" - seems like [conference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conference) or [journal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal) are a more natural fit than [paper-submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-submission).

I therefore propose to narrow the scope of the [paper-submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-submission) tag as follows:

> On the process of submitting a paper for review or publication by a conference or journal. Typical questions with this tag relate to selection of preferred or conflicted reviewers, timeline of the submission process, and typesetting or compilation by the publisher.

Examples of questions within the scope of this tag would include:

- [Is there any paper submission deadline timezone convention?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28529/is-there-any-paper-submission-deadline-timezone-convention)
- [On a Conflict of Interest disclosure, what's the difference between 'ongoing' and 'current'?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27090/on-a-conflict-of-interest-disclosure-whats-the-difference-between-ongoing-an)
- [What typesetters do with the submitted paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26489/what-typesetters-do-with-the-submitted-paper)
- [Is it okay to inquire about the status of a paper when the online submission system shows no update three months after submission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24162/is-it-okay-to-inquire-about-the-status-of-a-paper-when-the-online-submission-sys)
- [How much time is usually left for authors to return page proofs? What happens if I am late?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23387/how-much-time-is-usually-left-for-authors-to-return-page-proofs-what-happens-if)

but would not include other aspects of manuscript preparation, such as deciding what content should go in the paper, or what journal to submit to.

For those new to meta: voting on meta is  different from voting on the main site. Vote this post *up* if you agree overall with the proposed change in scope; vote *down* if you disagree with the proposed change.

If you would like to express arguments for or against the proposed change, or suggest minor changes to this proposal, write an answer!